# Jquery find number of table rows with specific values in 2 columns

Tags: jquery, html-table, is-empty

I have a table with 2 columns "id" (unique value) and "name". Using jQuery I would like to return the number (.length) of rows where the ID matches an array of ids (e.g. SR1, B1, B2) AND the value in the "name" field for those rows is empty.

So far I have:

```
var empty = $('[tabulator-field="name"]:empty').length;
var sr1 = $('.tabulator-row:nth-of-type(29) [tabulator-field="name"]:empty').length;
var sr2 = $('.tabulator-row:nth-of-type(30) [tabulator-field="name"]:empty').length;
var b1 = $('.tabulator-row:nth-of-type(7) [tabulator-field="name"]:empty').length;
var b2 = $('.tabulator-row:nth-of-type(8) [tabulator-field="name"]:empty').length;
var c10 = $('.tabulator-row:nth-of-type(27) [tabulator-field="name"]:empty').length;
var c11 = $('.tabulator-row:nth-of-type(28) [tabulator-field="name"]:empty').length;
var emptySR = sr1 + sr2 + b1 + b2 + c10 + c11;
var emptyBeds = empty - emptySR;
```

However, this seems like an inefficient way to calculate this and furthermore, selecting the rows I am interested in by their position in the table (rather than by their ID values) using :nth-of-type returns incorrect results if the table is sorted by a different field as the order of rows will change.

Please can anyone suggest a robust function for achieving what I need?

Comment: Please click the `<>` and post a [mcve]

Comment: Not sure why I need to post an example - this is a straightforward question about selecting and filtering elements using jQuery and the context is well described in my opening paragraph.

Comment: @TomHeaps A spinet of the actual html would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks but the question has already been answered by somebody who didn't need to see an html table example with several rows and two columns titled "id" and "name" :)

Comment: @TomHeaps - then you were lucky. It is considered normal practice to post a [mcve] so we do not have to waste our time writing or second guessing your code and it aids us in testing our solutions on your actual html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a selector to match the empty field, then use a filter function to test if the ID is in the array.

```
var bedIds = ['SR1', 'SR2', 'B1', 'B2', 'C10', 'C11'];
var emptyBeds = $('.tabulator-row:has([tabulator-field="name"]:empty) [tabulator-field="id"]').filter(function() {
    return bedIds.indexOf(this.textContent) != -1;
}).length;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response - this code does exactly what I needed it to and in a much better way than I could have written!